# Blacklisted Broadcom drivers are still loaded

Tags: linux, drivers, opensuse, modprobe

I have certain Broadcom drivers clearly blacklisted in `50-broadcom-wl-blacklist.conf` file in `/etc/modprobe.d/`:

```
# modules blacklisted for broadcom-wl
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist ssb
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ndiswrapper
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist bcma
blacklist brcmsmac
```

But they are still being loaded!

```
$ lsmod | grep b43
b43legacy             151552  0
b43                   450560  0
bcma                   61440  1 b43
mac80211              888832  2 b43,b43legacy
ssb                    86016  2 b43,b43legacy
mmc_core              163840  2 b43,ssb
cfg80211              696320  4 wl,b43,mac80211,b43legacy
```

OS: openSUSE Leap 15

Some other posts mention running `mkinitrd` or `dracut`. When is this relevant for blacklisting modules?

Note, `50-broadcom-wl-blacklist.conf` was probably created by some openSUSE tool, I don't remember creating it. Strange that tool wouldn't call a `mkinitrd` if it was necessary.

We are living in `systemd` era, but I don't think `systemd` is not relevant for blacklisting modules (yet).

I am blacklisting this modules because I have to use Broadcom proprietary STA driver with my bcm4360 chipset card.

Comment: Also asked on openSuse forum: https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/535605-How-to-correctly-blacklist-a-driver-module-My-blacklisted-Broadcom-drivers-are-still-loaded

Answer (score 0):

So it turned out the blacklisted modules were explicitly loaded by one of Systemd / Network Manager services: `pullin-bcm43xx-firmware.service`.

I simply disabled the suspicious service via systemd call:
`systemctl disable pullin-bcm43xx-firmware.service`
and rebooted ..and voilà ..b43 drivers are not loaded anymore; ssb, b43, b43legacy, mac80211; only wl is present. Happy ending ..for now.

How I found `pullin-bcm43xx-firmware.service`? By a bit of detective work. By searching system log `journalctl -b`, searching for `b43`. I found this suspicious line:
`install_bcm43xx_firmware_wrapper[1115]: Downloading b43 firmware`
just after Network Manager started. Searching for `install_bcm43xx_firmware_wrapper` in `/etc` yielded `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/pullin-bcm43xx-firmware.service` ..and the rest you already know.

What is worring, I found it mostly by sheer luck. If that script didn't mention `b43` and its name I would be able to make any links. It worrying that there is no formal log trace of which drivers are loaded when and by whom :(

I also learned that module blacklisting is a bit misnomer. As Arvidjaar clarified it for me:

> Blacklist only prevents loading of module due to hardware
>   autodetection (strictly speaking, it tells modprobe to ignore internal
>   aliases provided by module). It does not prohibit loading of module by
>   any other means (explicit modprobe, install line in modprobe.conf,
>   explicit alias in modprobe.conf).

Kernel should have a proper enforceable blacklisting facility!

Comment: If you want to actively block the loading of a particular module, you can do it by adding `install hated-module-name /bin/true` to `/etc/modprobe.d/*.conf`. This overrides the usual `modprobe` command to load the module with `/bin/true`, and so an attempt to load the module will do nothing at all. Of course, if you are root (and the CAP_SYS_MODULE capability is not withdrawn) you can use `modprobe -i`, `insmod` or straight up make your own `init_module(2)` system call to load a module anyway...